# Цикл, доходя до кнопки останавливается, а по нажатию на нее продолжает работу

Tags: javascript, button, циклы

Что-то типа теста по математике для малышей. Есть форма на странице. В поля пользователь вводит количество примеров и в каких пределах выводить примеры (до 10, до 20 и т.п.).

Интересует как сделать цикл, который будет выводить примеры по очереди после нажатия на кнопку с вариантом ответа (неважно верный или нет)?

В приведенном примере формируется три примера на сумму не более 10. Примеры создаются, но показывает только последний. А как сделать чтобы показывались поочередно по нажатию на кнопку с ответом?

```
function summa(3,10){
  var count =0;
  while (count<3){
  var s=0;
  var firstAmp = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); //первое слогаемое
  var secondAmp = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); //второе слогаемое
  s=firstAmp+secondAmp ; //вычисляем сумму
  if (s>10 || s==0) {continue;} //если сумма больше 10 или равна 0 идем в начало цикла
  else{//выводим пример
    document.getElementById("primer").innerHTML = '<h1>' + firstAmp + " + " + secondAmp +'</h1>';               
  }
  var x= s+1;
  var y= s-1;
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  var var1 = '<input type= "button" onclick=alert("Good") value =' + s + '>';
  var var2 = '<input type= "button" onclick=alert("Bad") value =' + x + '>';
  var var3 = '<input type= "button" onclick=alert("Bad") value =' + y + '>';

  if (rand==1){
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = var1 + var2 + var3;   
  }else if(rand==2){
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = var2 + var1 + var3;
  }else {
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = var3 + var2 + var1;
  }
  count++;
  }
}
```

Извиняюсь если вдруг не понятно. Если совсем просто то вот так:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  alert ("i = "+i);
}
```

Здесь цикл прерывается алертом. А мне необходимо прерывание при ожидании одного из вариантов ответа. 
Спасибо.

Спасибо за советы. Вот как повернул своё решение:

```
function summa(3,10){
  var examples = new Array();
  //1-й вариант
  //for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
  while (examples.length<3){
  //2-й вариант
  //for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
  var firstAmp = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); //первое слогаемое
  var secondAmp = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); //второе слогаемое
  var s=firstAmp + secondAmp; //сумма
  if (s>10){continue;}
  else {
  var test = '<h1>' + firstAmp + " + " + secondAmp +'</h1>';
  } 
  var x= s+1;
  var y= s-1;
  //3-й вариант
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++){          
  var startTestForm = '<div id="testForm'+i+'">';
  var endTestForm = '</div>';
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  var var1 = '<input type= "button" onclick=document.getElementById("testForm' +i+'").style.display="none" value =' + s + '>';
  var var2 = '<input type= "button" onclick=document.getElementById("testForm' +i+'").style.display="none" value =' + x + '>';
  var var3 = '<input type= "button" onclick=document.getElementById("testForm' +i+'").style.display="none" value =' + y + '>';
  if (rand==1){
  examples.push(test + startTestForm + var1 + var2 + var3 + endTestForm);   
  }else if(rand==2){
  examples.push(test + startTestForm + var2 + var1 + var3 + endTestForm);
  }else {
  examples.push(test + startTestForm + var3 + var2 + var1 + endTestForm);
  }
  }//это конец цикла for
  }
  document.getElementById("primer").innerHTML = examples.join('');
  alert (examples.join(" !!! ")); //alert для контроля тогог, что попадает в examples
}
```

Добавил цикл for для вывода кнопок с вариантами ответов в отдельные div'ы чтобы они потом при нажатии исчезали.
Правда есть одно "но".
Лучший результат показывается при третьем варианте расположения: появляется необходимое количество div'ов с кнопками. При нажатии они исчезают. Но примеры везде одинаковые. 
При первом и втором вариантах расположения появляется больше примеров и div'ы нумеруются не по порядку и повторяются (div2, div0, div1, div3, div2 и т.п.). Хотя примеры разные.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где правильнее расположить цикл for.
Спасибо.

Comment: можно посмотреть в сторону [генераторов и yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: ответ надо оформить как ответ.

Comment: @Grundy Это был не совсем ответ. Там есть дополнительный вопрос. Или стоит его опубликовать как новый вопрос?

Comment: Так как на основной вопрос ответ уже дан - вряд ли кто вообще заметит, что в _ответе опубликованном в вопросе_ есть еще один дополнительный вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо. Понял. Буду оформлять новый вопрос.

Comment: При оформлении обрати внимание на то, что в текущем виде твой вопрос - абсолютно непонятен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сформировали все три примера, но `document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = ...` полностью перетирает предыдущие оставляя лишь последний. Сделайте примерно так:

```
var examples = [];
while (examples.length < 3){
  var s = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1; //сумма
  var firstAmp = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); //первое слогаемое
  var secondAmp = s - firstAmp; //второе слогаемое
  var test = '<h1>' + firstAmp + " + " + secondAmp +'</h1>';               
  var x= s+1;
  var y= s-1;
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  var var1 = '<input type= "button" onclick=alert("Good") value =' + s + '>';
  var var2 = '<input type= "button" onclick=alert("Bad") value =' + x + '>';
  var var3 = '<input type= "button" onclick=alert("Bad") value =' + y + '>';
  if (rand==1){
    examples.push(test + var1 + var2 + var3);   
  }else if(rand==2){
    examples.push(test + var2 + var1 + var3);
  }else {
    examples.push(test + var3 + var2 + var1);
  }
}
document.getElementById("primer").innerHTML = examples.join('');
```

это покажет сразу три примера с тремя вариантами ответа для каждого

Comment: Спасибо. Это решение натолкнуло меня на другой путь решения. Придется повозиться с таблицей (где-то я видел такую реализацию). Хотя если есть способ обойтись без таблицы буду рад его рассмотреть.

Comment: можно так: `document.getElementById("primer").innerHTML = '<div>'+examples.join('</div><div>')+'</div>;`

Comment: можно так: examples.push('<div class="example">'+test + var3 + var2 + var1+'<\div>');